# Disable TLS 1.3 on IIS

Tags: ssl, iis

After July 2020 Windows update, a IIS hosted website started using TLS 1.3 when I need it to be TLS 1.2 for inbound SSL inspection to avoid ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH errors.  How can I disable TLS 1.3?

Answer (score 2):

A Microsoft article on [Transport Layer Security (TLS) registry settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/tls-registry-settings#tls-12) describes how this is done for SSL 2.0, SSL 3.0, TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, TLS 1.2, DTLS 1.0 and DTLS 1.2. There's no reason to believe this would be done any other way for TLS 1.3, although not yet documented.

It's also worth mentioning you'd only create keys to change the defaults from [Protocols in TLS/SSL (Schannel SSP)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-) – that explains why those keys don't exist by default.

### Disable TLS 1.3 as server protocol

[Managing SSL/TLS Protocols and Cipher Suites for AD FS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/manage-ssl-protocols-in-ad-fs) lists the actual registry keys better and also has PowerShell examples. The following is modified from there.

**...using .reg file (Registry Editor):**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Server]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
```

**...using PowerShell:**

```
New-Item `
   'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Server' `
   -Force | Out-Null
    
New-ItemProperty `
   -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Server' `
   -name 'Enabled' -value '0' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
    
New-ItemProperty `
   -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Server' `
   -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 1 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've already tried setting DisabledByDefault=1 and Enabled=0 a few times with reboots on the reverse proxy with IIS, internal IIS server, and client machine with no success.  I also am trying to disable TLS 1.3 on Google Chrome, but have been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: I've also explicitly turned off TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 and TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, but then the site becomes inaccessible..

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Server 2022, the IIS binding can be configured without TLS 1.3:

[image]

This will cause IIS to fallback to TLS 1.2 if it is available.